# Sort Rows of Dynamic Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have the following query to dynamically pivot some row information:

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(char(50), ScheduleEndTime, 120))
                   FROM metersNotRead
                   group by ScheduleEndTime
                   order by ScheduleEndTime DESC
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                   ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                   ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'SELECT ScheduleName, MeterID, CurrentGK,
                ' + @cols + ' from 
                 (
                    select ScheduleName, MeterID, CurrentGK, ScheduleEndTime, ''Y'' flag
                    from metersNotRead
                ) x
                pivot 
                (
                    max(flag)
                    for ScheduleEndTime in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p 
                order by ' + @cols +' DESC
        '

    execute(@query)
```

It gives me the correct results, but I am wondering how I can sort the rows by the first dynamic column, then the second, and so on, until all dynamic columns have been ordered by.

The results I have now are like this:

```
ScheduleName   MeterID   CurrentGK    FirstDynamicCol    SecondDynamicCol    ETC
textName1      exampleID1  --         NULL               Y                   
taxtName2      exampleID2  --         Y                  NULL
```

I want them to be like this:

```
ScheduleName   MeterID   CurrentGK    FirstDynamicCol    SecondDynamicCol    ETC
textName2      exampleID2  --         Y                  NULL                   
taxtName1      exampleID1  --         NULL               Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, put your first column name in its own variable, and order by that only.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @orderby NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @orderby = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(char(50), ScheduleEndTime, 120)) + ' desc'
               FROM metersNotRead
               group by ScheduleEndTime
               order by ScheduleEndTime DESC
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
               ,1,1,'')

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(char(50), ScheduleEndTime, 120))
               FROM metersNotRead
               group by ScheduleEndTime
               order by ScheduleEndTime DESC
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
               ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
               ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ScheduleName, MeterID, CurrentGK,
            ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select ScheduleName, MeterID, CurrentGK, ScheduleEndTime, ''Y'' flag
                from metersNotRead
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(flag)
                for ScheduleEndTime in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
            order by ' + @orderby


execute(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks @JiggsJedi that brings me closer to what I need. But, I actually want it sorted by all dynamic columns. If the columns were '2014-06-19' '2014-06-18' '2014-06-17' I would want the order by clause to be "order by '2014-06-19' DESC, '2014-06-18' DESC,  '2014-06-17' DESC". I used the code from the 'select cols' to set the 'select orderby' to all of the dynamic columns but I am not sure how to get the 'DESC' after each column.

Comment: Updated answer.  If it's not right, take a look at what it's doing with a `PRINT @ORDERBY` right after you set it (just run to there), then you can tweak it as need be.

Comment: That's perfect! Although I had to remove the 'DESC' from the query section of the code or else I got a syntax error because of the extra 'DESC'. I updated your code and have accepted your answer. Thank you for the help!